# Wine problem to launch steam games (windows versions)

Tags: wine, games, steam

i download stonghold 2 steam edition from a site in ubuntu 20.04 and it work in ubuntu 19.04 but now when i wanna launch it wine give me the following message

the important think about it is only steam games (the versions of games that are for windows) has this problem and for example in stronghold 2 (2005) i havent this problem and game launch without problem

[you can see the following error in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KbQa.png)

Comment: I'm confused. You say it works in Ubuntu 19 (I'm assuming in Steam w/Proton), but not in Wine? Why are you trying to run it in Wine when Steam is already using its own version (with Proton)?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  There is no Ubuntu 19, and *snap* based releases that use *yy* format are only released on *even* years, all desktop and server or *deb* based releases that come out each year are however *yy.mm* in format with all 2019 releases are now being EOL

Comment: @ajgringo619 becuase this is not a free game in steam and is a cracked version so need be launch as binary not in client. and in ubuntu you need to launch it with wine. i haven't this problem in ubuntu 19.04 but in 20.04 have

Comment: Did you install the same version of Wine? If so, then you'll probably need to check on its gaming forum to see if anyone else has had this problem.

Comment: as you know @ajgringo619 i told this is a cracked version of game and it's be used for old users of this games such as me. in crack version you can't play online and only could see the graphics and gameplay and i only wanna this game because of my nostalgia. and cause this version is a cracked version so i cant ask my questions in every forums.

Comment: @guiverc i added my os details